# ABP Commercial DateTime Picker Not Populating values on Edit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor, abp

In ABP commercial previously date was saving like this

**CREATE**

```
<abp-input asp-for="TaxCodeEffectiveLife.StartDateTime" value="" type="date" />
```

While editing the records we have rezor syntax like this

**EDIT**

```
<abp-input asp-for="TaxCodeEffectiveLife.StartDateTime" value="@(Model.TaxCodeEffectiveLife.StartDateTime?.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))" type="date" />
```

Now I wanted to give user ability to change date and also time so I change the **type="datetime-local"**

It worked for me, and I was able to change and save date and time both.
Now when I try to edit the records. It is not populating date time. It is populating date only with **type="date"** but not time when i change it to **datetime-local**.

I tried to give the control value by jQuery it did not work. I also tried to change the date format in edit from  **yyyy-MM-dd** to **yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm tt** and try to give other formats. It is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have resolved this.
This is how I implement the edit option

I have a hidden value for the StartDateTime in the .chtml file

```
<input type="hidden" id="StartDateTime" name="StartDateTime" value="@Model.TaxCodeEffectiveLife.StartDateTime" />
```

This is the UI element for the star Date

```
<div class="form-group pmd-textfield pmd-textfield-floating-label">
    <label for="regular1" class="control-label">@L["StartDateTime"]</label>
    <div class="input-group date" id="TaxCodeEffectiveLife_StartDateTime" data-target-input="nearest">
        <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#TaxCodeEffectiveLife_StartDateTime" name="TaxCodeEffectiveLife.StartDateTime" />
        <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#TaxCodeEffectiveLife_StartDateTime" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
            <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You will need to add this to your JavaSript file as well .js

```
    $('#TaxCodeEffectiveLife_StartDateTime').datetimepicker({
        date: new Date($('#StartDate').val()),
        format: "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"
    });
```